# Clearfix doesn't work when I want multiple images superposing

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I want 3 images on top of each other (so i can switch between them with the slider). I use the relative/absolute technique.
Strangely, the result is floating outside the div (see the picture below).
When I try to fix it with clearfix, it just cancel the superposition.

Any help ?

Here is a part of my css :

```
body {

img {
  width: 900px;
}

#parentsuperpose {
     position: relative;
}

img.superpose {
 position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   left: 25px;
}

#img1 {
   z-index: 10;
}
#img2 {
 z-index: 11;
}
#img3 {
   z-index: 12;
}
```

Here is part of my HTML

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12" id="parentsuperpose">
                  <img src="images/mur01.jpg" class="superpose" id="img1" alt="mur01" style="visibility:visible;">              
                  <img src="images/mur02.jpg" class="superpose" id="img2" alt="mur02" style="visibility:hidden;">
                  <img src="images/mur03.jpg" class="superpose" id="img3" alt="mur03" style="visibility:hidden;">
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEub8.png)

Comment: One of the images should have `position:relative`, to make the parent expand.

Comment: I tried what you said Andrei. It works, but the image with position:relative are not aligned anymore with the other.